# Podem me ajudar nesse relacionamento de tabela?

Tags: sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```sql
CREATE TABLE ALUNO
(
    NR_RGM NUMBER (8,0) NOT NULL,
    NM_NOME VARCHAR2 (40) NOT NULL,
    NM_PAI VARCHAR2 (40),
    NM_MAE VARCHAR2 (40),
    DT_NASCIMENTO DATE NOT NULL,
    ID_SEXO CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_RGM PRIMARY KEY (NR_RGM)
    
);

CREATE TABLE MATRICULA 
(
    NR_RGM NUMBER (8,0) NOT NULL,
    CD_CLASSE NUMBER (8,0) NOT NULL,
    DT_MATRICULA DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MATRICULA PRIMARY KEY (NR_RGM, CD_CLASSE),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MATRICULA_REF_ALUNO FOREIGN KEY (NR_RGM)
        REFERENCES ALUNO (NR_RGM)
);


CREATE TABLE CLASSE
(
    CD_CLASSE NUMBER (8,0)NOT NULL,
    NR_ANOLETIVO NUMBER (4,0)NOT NULL,
    NR_SERIE NUMBER (2,0)NOT NULL,
    SG_TURMA VARCHAR2 (2,0)NOT NULL,
    CD_ESCOLA NUMBER (6,0)NOT NULL,
    CD_GRAU NUMBER (2,0)NOT NULL,
    CD_PERIODO NUMBER (2,0)NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_CLASSE PRIMARY KEY (CD_CLASSE),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CLASSE_REF_MATRICULA FOREIGN KEY (CD_CLASSE)
        REFERENCES MATRICULA (CD_CLASSE)
);
```

Quando tento criar a tabela de classe aparece esse erro:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabela **CLASSE** o campo do tipo **VARCHAR2** **SG_TURMA** não deve ter vírgula na declaração do tamanho:

- Invés de `SG_TURMA VARCHAR2 (2,0)NOT NULL,`
- Declare  `SG_TURMA VARCHAR2 (2)NOT NULL,`